# pledge your first-born child to Microsoft -- I don't understand what that means

Tags: comprehension, figurative-language

From a book called [*Access 2013: The Missing Manual*](http://www.oreilly.com/pub/missingmanuals/access2013mm):

> At this point, you're probably wondering how much that part in the center of Figure
>   21-1—the SQL Server database engine—actually costs. Microsoft sets the price using
>   a complex licensing scheme that ratchets up the cost depending on how many
>   people use the database at once. Usually, it runs into thousands of dollars, and it's
>   not uncommon for a big business to shell out $20,000 or more.
>   But before you skip this chapter in disgust, there's something you should know: A completely free version of SQL Server is out there waiting for you. Amazingly enough, it's almost as powerful as the one that costs thousands of dollars and requires you to **pledge your first-born child to Microsoft**.

Honestly, I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The phrase *"pledge your first-born child to"* is a sarcastic figure of speech, akin to *"sell your soul to"*. It's saying that someone is asking you to pay too high a price for something, and is often used when you might be getting yourself into a situation that could be hard to get out of later.

In the context of technology, it's often used to say that you'll be tied to a certain platform or system, and switching might be difficult or costly.

For example, say a mobile phone company is offering you a free phone, but you'll need to sign a two-year contract to get it. Some people might think that's too long to commit to one carrier, particularly if you could buy the phone yourself at a reasonable price. In that case, the person who is advising you to reconsider that "deal" might say something like:

> Sure, you get a free phone – but, to get it, you have to pledge your first-born child to the carrier.

or, similarly:

> Sure, you get a free phone – but you have to sell your soul to get it.

It's very figurative speech to say you might regret something down the road.

Comment: It's also a reference to classic fairy tales like [Rumplestiltskin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumpelstiltskin) in which a wish is granted in return for pledging their first-born child to the wish granter.

Comment: @Jim - Thanks for the footnote! (BTW, I'd upvote that if you left it as an answer, too.)

Comment: Although be aware that 'sell your soul' has a connotation that afterwards you belong to the buyer, which 'pledge your first-born child' doesn't.

Comment: @dbmag9 - Yes, but presumably the love between parent and child is strong enough that the consequences are regarded as nearly equally dire.

Comment: I don't think that's the usual connotation. If I sell my soul to Big Company X the idea is that they can then control me and what I do; if I sell my first-born child to them I've just paid a high price, but I wouldn't take that to mean they control me. It's an idiom that treats children as property, not as beloved individuals.

Comment: @dbmag9 - I see what you're getting at now. Thanks for clarifying. I may end up editing this post if you don't end up leaving a better answer. :^)